# how to always make MS Word open in outline mode at level 1

Tags: microsoft-word

When I open Word, how can I set it so that it always opens in View > Outline mode, and showing only level 1 headings?

I primarily use Word for making notes in Outline mode because it has pretty good collapse/expand control, and I can paste *anything* into Word.  (Been doing this over 20 years.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to have all our Word docs automatically open in Outline View level 1.
(Halleluiah!)

1. Click "File" in the Word ribbon and click "Options" to open the Word Options window.
2. Click "Customize Ribbon" and check the box next to Developer. (It's there -- look for it!)   Click "OK."
3. Click "Developer" in the ribbon, and then click "Macros" in the Code group to open the Macros dialog box.
4. Type "AutoOpen" in the Macro Name box.
5. Click "Create" to open Word's Visual Basic editor. The editor includes the following code for your macro:

   ```
   Sub AutoOpen() 
   ' 
   ' AutoOpen Macro
   ' 
   ' 
   End Sub
   ```
6. Add the following lines within the macro code above `End Sub`:

   ```
   ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdOutlineView
   ActiveWindow.View.ShowHeading 1
   ```

   The entire macro reads as follows:

   ```
   Sub AutoOpen()
   '
   ' AutoOpen Macro
   '
   '
   ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdOutlineView
   ActiveWindow.View.ShowHeading 1
   End Sub
   ```
7. Click the disk icon to save the macro to make Word open all documents using Outline view.

Thanks to:
http://smallbusiness.chron.com/make-print-layout-default-layout-microsoft-word-45080.html

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: Still works as of Sept 2018 and on Office 365 Word.